# Is "Von was für ein glückliches Leben redest du" correct?

Tags: grammar, preposition, adverb

X said to Y:

> Ich wünsche dir ein glückliches Leben voll von dem Gutem zu dir.

Y was hopeless, so he said:

> Von was für ein glückliches Leben redest du?

Are those sentences above correct?

Comment: Well, no they aren't. - However, you tagged them with "prepositions" and "adverbs". Maybe you could tell us what exactly it is, your unsure about. I removed tag "translation" as there's no original English sentence in your question.

Comment: First sentence: "voll von Gutem" without the article because there is no specific "good" to point at, also, remove the second "zu dir". The first "dir" makes that clear already. Second sentence... you'd have to use Dative because it's "von" "Von was für einem glücklichen Leben..."

Comment: "ein glückliches Leben voll von Gutem" is not idiomatically correct German even after you remove the article.

Answer (score 2):

I corrected your sentences a little bit:

X said to Y:

```
"Ich wünsche Dir ein glückliches Leben und alles Gute für Dich."
```

Y was hopeless, so he said:

```
"Von was für einem glücklichen Leben redest du?"
```

Hope this is what you wanted to express.

Comment: I find the second "für Dich" redundant. The Dative make it clear who the wish is directed to. Adding a second target that is identical with the first is weird.

Comment: That's right. I just wanted to make it as similar as possible to the given sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich wünsche dir ein glückliches Leben voll von  Gutem.

*das Gute* is an abstract noun. You must not use **dem**.

*Ich wünsche dir* gives already the addressee so **zu dir** is not needed (and wrong, cause in such a case actually e. g. **für dich** would be used)

> Von was für **einem glücklichen** Leben redest du?

**von** requires the dative (`von dem glücklichen Leben`)